# Using Javascript to Search and Display info from XML file

Tags: javascript, html, xml

I am currently creating an online dictionary.

I have an XML document with the information from the Dictionary stored like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<dictionary>
    <norman>
        <entry>A 1. the male or positive principle, yang 2. convex, raised 3.interjection ofresponse 4. interjection of fear S. vocative particle 6. a tooth in the Manchuscript A A an interjection of casual response </entry>
        <entry>A I BUKDAN the outside edge of a piece of folded paper </entry>
        <entry>A JIJUN I ACANGGA a bronze identification token with raised characters used togain admittance to a city at night </entry>
        <entry>A JILGAN a yang tone in music A FA SERE ONGGOLO see afanggala </entry>
        <entry>A SI a sound used for driving chickens or birds </entry>
        <entry>A TA (onom.) the sound of a commotion ABA 1. hunt, battue 2. where 
    </norman>
</dictionary>
```

My HTML looks like this:

```
<input type="text" name="entry" id="input">
<br />
<input type="submit" value="Submit" onClick="searchXML()">
<br />
<br />
<div id="results">
</div>
```

I want a user to be able to search a word like "JIJUN" and then have a return of every entry (the whole line) with that word in it and display in the "results" DIV

my main problem is I have no idea about going about implementing this with javascript, a push in the right direction would be really helpful, a complete answer would be awesome. I have used other examples on stack exchange but none have been much help.

Thank you

Comment: Parsing XML with JavaScript is no fun. Try to get the data in some kind of JSON format.

Comment: How big are your XML files, are you doing this frontend or can you use node?

Comment: @DanielKobe As of right now my XML file is ~1MB, I am doing this frontend, I am not acquainted with node

Comment: @DanielKobe Planning on using multiple dictionaries eventually, would just like to get this one running for the time being

Comment: @Daniel will definitely look into that, but for now I would like to stick with javascript, I have over 23k entries and am not ready to start messing with how they are set up. Thanks though!

Comment: I like using autocomplete, here is an example - https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/

Comment: What about: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/mVVMZQ

Comment: @Daniel WOW you are awesome!

Comment: @Daniel Thank you very much for this. do you know if there is anyway to not make it case sensetive?

Comment: should be case sensitive. you mean case insensitive?

Comment: search for "BUKDAN" you will get a match. search for "budokan" you will get no match

Comment: Yes, I would like to be able to search for it in lowercase as well, Not sure if that is possible. Sorry for asking so much btw!

Comment: see here: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/mVVMZQ

Answer (score 2):

If the file is very large, it will be slow no matter what because you are searching for text in a large string essentially. UPDATE: saw comment that it is 23k line file, this is probably a few megabytes so expect users to load slowly the first time.

You could load the XML into a string, then find the first instance of the search term, call a function to append the entry to your result DIV.  Then from the end of the entry you just identified or if you are lazy from the character after the search term ends, run the search again.

The function to append will just search backwards from your search term hit (character offset index location in the string) for `<entry>` and forward to the string `</entry>`.

To code both of these functions you mainly need the String function [indexOf](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_indexof.asp).

[jsFiddle solution here](https://jsfiddle.net/qxk4yqsp/1/)

Not sure why, but the solution gives an error on JSFiddle that it cant find the searchXML function. It works fine when you save it into a .html file and open it in browser.

*NOTE: I removed the line breaks in your XML file to quickly mock up the example, you can load the XML into a string [this way](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/tryit.asp?filename=try_dom_loadxmldoc).

**HTML**

```
<body>
<input id="srch" type="text" >
<br />
<input  type="submit" value="Submit" onClick="searchXML()">
<br />
<br />
<div id="results">
</div>
</body>
```

**JS**

```
var dict = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><dictionary>    <norman>        <entry>A 1. the male or positive principle, yang 2. convex, raised 3.interjection ofresponse 4. interjection of fear S. vocative particle 6. a tooth in the Manchuscript A A an interjection of casual response </entry>        <entry>A I BUKDAN the outside edge of a piece of folded paper </entry>        <entry>A JIJUN I ACANGGA a bronze identification token with raised characters used togain admittance to a city at night </entry>        <entry>A JILGAN a yang tone in music A FA SERE ONGGOLO see afanggala </entry>        <entry>A SI a sound used for driving chickens or birds </entry>        <entry>A TA (onom.) the sound of a commotion ABA 1. hunt, battue 2. where     </norman></dictionary>';
//NOTE: if your XML contains any ' characters it will break.. search replace your dictionary for the ' character first replace it with " maybe, this is the fastest solution to this, ok if your dictionary is not dynamic

function searchXML() {

  var term = document.getElementById('srch').value;

  getNextEntry(term, 0, dict.length-1);
}

function getNextEntry(term, startIndexPos, endIndexPos){

    var n = dict.indexOf(term, startIndexPos,endIndexPos);
    if (n > 0) {
        //found hit
        addHitToDIV(n);
        getNextEntry(term, n + term.length + 1, endIndexPos);

    } else {
        //done searching

        return -1;
     }


}
function addHitToDIV(startIndexPos) {
    var fullEntry;
    var first = dict.lastIndexOf("<entry>", startIndexPos);
    var last = dict.indexOf("</entry>", startIndexPos,dict.length-1);
    document.getElementById('results').innerHTML = document.getElementById('results').innerHTML + "<p>" + dict.substring(first+7, last-1) + "</p><br>";
}
```

[image]