# Split Javascript String into an array of strings by looking for keyword

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, string

Working on a personal project that parses through an HTML document inserted into a textarea and produces a new HTML document with added modifications. 
What my issue is, I want split certain divs with class="dog" into an array with each element in the array being divs of class of dog.

HTML:

```
<div class="dog">
    <div class="mouth"></div>
    <dig class="legs"></dig>
</div>
<div class="dog">
    <div class="mouth"></div>
    <dig class="legs"></dig>
</div>
```

JS Idea:

```
dogs[x] = intext.slice(intext.indexOf('<div class="dog"'), /*next instance of dog*/);
```

Array would look like:

```
dog[0] = <div class="dog">
        <div class="mouth"></div>
        <dig class="legs"></dig>
    </div>
```

I tried using `.indexOf('<div class="dog"')` to try and create an array of indexes so I can use it to split the main string but no luck.

Any ideas of how I can accomplish this?

Comment: Why not parse it as HTML in a parser, and work with built in methods instead.

Comment: var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('dog');

Comment: I see what your saying, however I am taking in the javascript as an input from a textarea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to load the content onto the DOM:

```
document.createElement("div").innerHtml(intext);
```

Then you can find the dog elements as the other answers have suggested:

```
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('dog');
```

Be careful when loading user inputted data into the DOM, this can open doors to being hacked.

Comment: As long as it's strictly on the client's side the vulnerability is not really a concern, right?

Comment: Yes, I am only using this for personal use (will be modifying existing html with new classes). But I am taking in the input through text area and not the DOM. Is there a similar solution using plain string methods?

Comment: @FroyT Yes, the way you started to do it is *possible* however it is the worst way you could approach this.  You will quickly be absolutely miserable.  Use this solution and you can do things like `element.className += " " + newClassName;` whereas if you do it with string manipulation you will spend hours trying to count characters and parse simple elements.

Answer (score 3):

There exists a feature called query selectors. With these you can select all elements with a certain class, or all elements of a certain tag, ...

This will suit your specific need: [querySelectorAll](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_queryselectorall.asp)

the regular `querySelector()` will only select the first element which is why you need to use `querySelectorAll()`. It will give you a list of elements with which you can continue working.

**Example:**

```
var dogDivs = document.querySelectorAll(".dog");
```

**EDIT:**
As you have just now mentioned it is text from a textarea, as suggested by [an other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34730635/2686165) you could first load it into your DOM structure. Preferrably in a hidden element so that the user is unaware of it.

Comment: What If i have  element with class "dog" that is not div?

Comment: Then the list will be empty.

Comment: I didnt mention that I am retrieving the input through a textarea.

Answer (score 1):

You should never parse html as a string. Use a `DOMParser` to convert it to a document and then you can use all the standard methods

```
var parser = new DOMParser();
var doc = parser.parseFromString(stringContainingHTMLSource, "Text Area Content");

divs = doc.getElementsBYTagName("div");
```

Then you can use the built in `Document` interface. For your specific case, here are a few methods you can use.

get an array of all divs: 
`document.getElementsByTagName("div");`

get an array of all divs with a specific class:
`document.getElementsByClassName("dog");`

get an array of all divs with a specific id:
`document.getElementById("id");`

The full list of very useful methods can be found on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document).

Comment: I didnt mention that I am taking the input through textarea.

Comment: Updated it to work for the textarea. You should still avoid parsing manually at all cost.

Answer (score 0):

```
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('dog'); 
var arr = [].slice.call(elements);
```

arr is the array you want to have. elements is HTMLCollection, and doesn't have array prototype methods.

Answer (score 0):

You can try getting all elements with class dog:

```
var dogs = document.getElementsByClassName("dog");
```

But this will return all elements with class dog. Then you can try this snippet:

```
function splitByClass(tag, cl) {
 var els = document.getElementsByClassName(cl);

 var res = [];

 for (i = 0; i < els.length; i++) {
   if (els[i].tagName.toLowerCase() == tag.toLowerCase()) {
            res.push(els[i]);
   }
 }

 return res;
}

console.log(splitByClass("div","dog"));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to parse it as text without converting it into a DOM object which could potentially error if there is any mistakes with the users input formatting.  Try a solution like the one I suggested here for searching XML code:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/34299948/1011603

This will let you search for a start tag, eg  and an end tag, you just need to tweak the .substring sizing for the size of your search start/end tag eg the div.

Answer (score -1):

For the thing you are doing you don't use the slice tool. This would be used for a String and you don't use the index of because that's just searching a string for a specific part.

What you do want to use is the

```
document.querySelectorAll(".example");
```

You will put the class dog where the .example is as the same format.
This command will return an array of all of the possible divs

If you need any more help, go to this link
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_queryselectorall.asp